# simultaneous read and write to child's stdio using boost.process

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

i am trying to write and read to child's stdio using boost.process using something like this:

```
boost::asio::io_service writeService, readService;
bp::async_pipe in{writeService};
bp::async_pipe out{readService};

bp::child process(CompressCmd.c_str(), bp::std_in < in, bp::std_out > out);
Buffer src;
src.reserve(4 * 1024 * 1024);
integer_type read = 0;
//std::atomic_int64_t totalWrite{0};
integer_type totalWrite = 0;
while (callback(CallbackActions::NeedMoreInput, src, read)) {
    in.async_write_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(src.data(), read),
        [](const boost::system::error_code &e, std::size_t) { });
    // written data is not important, that's why using same buffer
    out.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(src.data(), src.capacity()),
                        [&](const boost::system::error_code &e,
                           std::size_t byte_transferred) { totalWrite += byte_transferred; });
}
writeService.run();
in.close();
readService.run();
```

all read and write operations are noitified as success but value of totalWrite is totally incorrect f.e reported 29356032, real value should be around 50000000
  
i noticed the program is terminating half way ,
 using process.wait() after readService.run() freezes child,
 using atomic int produces same behaviour 
 for now i actually only need to know how much data is actually wriiten, that's why i am using same buffer

Comment: `incorrect 29356032, real value 29356032` I see no difference.

Comment: What is the goal? How are you going to use the results?

Comment: Benchmarks different compressors on a part of file, use best of them and build a sort of database on top of data obtained sorted on entropy of provided data for compression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This pattern:

   ```
   while (callback(CallbackActions::NeedMoreInput, src, read)) {
       in.async_write_some(...);
       out.async_read_some(...);
   }
   ```

   is most likely misguided (async operations always immediately return, so you'd simply keep adding more async operations without giving them a chance to run).
2. Also misguided is the fact that you have separate services for the pipes, but you're running them in total exclusion, so no read operation will ever run until the writeService completes.
3. `atomic` types are misguided since there's no access from multiple threads
4. What are you trying to do? You reserve a large buffer but never put any data into it (`reserve` != `resize`). Therefore you can only hope to write nothing.

   Even more ironically, you are reading into the exact same buffer, at the exact same spot. However, that's immediately [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)¹ because you pass it `src.capacity()` when you know that `src.size()==0`.

   Even without that error how can you "simultaneously" read and write from exactly the same bytes in memory and still know what the expected outcome would be?
5. you are not passing your own `io_service` to Boost Process

### A Working Demo

Here's a working sample. Of course I had to guess what you actually want to do.

I opted to make the program send its own source (main.cpp) to stdin, and read stdout iteratively, recording the `total_received` bytes. It then prints the exit code and that total.

As a make-shift compressor I used `'/usr/bin/xxd'` because it's available and could even be usefully printed to `std::cout` for debugging.

**<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>** // trouble on Coliru

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>
std::vector<char> read_file(std::string const&);

namespace bp = boost::process;
using boost::system::error_code;

using Loop = boost::function<void()>;
using Buffer = std::array<char, 4*1024>;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    std::string const CompressCmd = "/usr/bin/xxd";

    bp::async_pipe in{svc}, out{svc};
    bp::child process(CompressCmd, bp::std_in < in, bp::std_out > out, svc);

    auto data = read_file("main.cpp");

    Loop read_loop, write_loop;

    Buffer recv_buffer;
    std::size_t total_received = 0;
    read_loop = [&read_loop, &out, &recv_buffer, &total_received] {
        out.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer),
            [&](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                std::cout << "ReadLoop: " << ec.message() << " got " << transferred << " bytes\n";
                total_received += transferred; 
                if (!ec)
                    read_loop(); // continue reading
            });
    };

    boost::asio::async_write(in, boost::asio::buffer(data),
        [&](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
            std::cout << "WriteLoop: " << ec.message() << " done, " << transferred << " bytes\n";
            in.close(ec);
            std::cout << "WriteLoop: closed pipe (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
        }); // async

    read_loop(); // async

    svc.run(); // Await all async operations

    std::cout << "Process exitcode " << process.exit_code() << ", total_received=" << total_received << "\n";
}

#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
std::vector<char> read_file(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream ifs(fname);
    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {}};
}
```

Printing

```
WriteLoop: Success done, 1787 bytes
WriteLoop: closed pipe (Success)
ReadLoop: Success got 4096 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 3515 bytes
ReadLoop: End of file got 0 bytes
Process exitcode 0, total_received=7611
```

### Explanations, Simplifications

Note that we do all of the writing without a loop. That's because `boost::asio::async_write` is a *composed operation* (it hides the loop).

Likewise, if you can "afford" to store the whole received data in memory, you can simplify by using `boost::asio::streambuf` and using a similar composed operation:

**<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>** // trouble on Coliru

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>
std::vector<char> read_file(std::string const&);

namespace bp = boost::process;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    std::string const CompressCmd = "/usr/bin/xxd";

    bp::async_pipe in{svc}, out{svc};
    bp::child process(CompressCmd, bp::std_in < in, bp::std_out > out, svc);

    auto data = read_file("main.cpp");

    boost::asio::streambuf recv_buffer;
    boost::asio::async_read(out, recv_buffer,
            [&](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                std::cout << "ReadLoop: " << ec.message() << " got " << transferred << " bytes\n";
            });

    boost::asio::async_write(in, boost::asio::buffer(data),
        [&](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
            std::cout << "WriteLoop: " << ec.message() << " done, " << transferred << " bytes\n";
            in.close(ec);
            std::cout << "WriteLoop: closed pipe (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
        }); // async

    svc.run(); // Await all async operations

    std::cout << "Process exitcode " << process.exit_code() << ", total_received=" << recv_buffer.size() << "\n";
}

#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
std::vector<char> read_file(std::string const& fname) {
    std::ifstream ifs(fname);
    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {}};
}
```

> Conversely, if you cannot afford to have all the data in memory before sending, you can create a loop to send input block-wise

### Two Asynchronous Loops, With Delays

Let's do that, and make it more entertaining by delaying a second before writing each block. What you'd expect to see is alternating reads/writes happening because of the delays:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dbfbfb9d23b1dd8)</kbd>** // yay running on Coliru

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace bp = boost::process;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using Loop = boost::function<void()>;
using Buffer = std::array<char, 500>;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    auto on_exit = [](int code, std::error_code ec) {
            std::cout << "Exited " << code << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
        };

    std::string const CompressCmd = "/usr/bin/xxd";

    bp::async_pipe in{svc}, out{svc};
    bp::child process(CompressCmd, bp::std_in < in, bp::std_out > out, svc, bp::on_exit(on_exit));

    Loop read_loop, write_loop;

    Buffer recv_buffer;
    std::size_t total_received = 0;
    read_loop = [&read_loop, &out, &recv_buffer, &total_received] {
        out.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer),
            [&](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                std::cout << "ReadLoop: " << ec.message() << " got " << transferred << " bytes\n";
                total_received += transferred; 
                if (!ec)
                    read_loop(); // continue reading
            });
    };

    std::ifstream ifs("main.cpp");
    std::size_t total_written = 0;
    Buffer send_buffer;
    boost::asio::high_resolution_timer send_delay(svc);
    write_loop = [&write_loop, &in, &ifs, &send_buffer, &total_written, &send_delay] {
        if (!ifs.good())
        {
            error_code ec;
            in.close(ec);
            std::cout << "WriteLoop: closed stdin (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
            return;
        }
        ifs.read(send_buffer.data(), send_buffer.size());

        boost::asio::async_write(in, boost::asio::buffer(send_buffer.data(), ifs.gcount()),
            [&](error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                std::cout << "WriteLoop: " << ec.message() << " sent " << transferred << " bytes\n";
                total_written += transferred; 
                if (!ec) {
                    send_delay.expires_from_now(1s);
                    send_delay.async_wait([&write_loop](error_code ec) {
                        std::cout << "WriteLoop: send delay " << ec.message() << "\n";
                        if (!ec) write_loop(); // continue writing
                    });
                }
            });
    };

    read_loop(); // async
    write_loop(); // async

    svc.run(); // Await all async operations

    std::cout << "Process exitcode " << process.exit_code() << ", total_received=" << total_received << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
WriteLoop: Success sent 500 bytes
WriteLoop: send delay Success
WriteLoop: Success sent 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 96 bytes
WriteLoop: send delay Success
WriteLoop: Success sent 500 bytes
WriteLoop: send delay Success
WriteLoop: Success sent 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 96 bytes
WriteLoop: send delay Success
WriteLoop: Success sent 500 bytes
WriteLoop: send delay Success
WriteLoop: Success sent 134 bytes
WriteLoop: send delay Success
WriteLoop: closed stdin (Success)
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 500 bytes
ReadLoop: Success got 22 bytes
Exited 0 (Success)
ReadLoop: End of file got 0 bytes
Process exitcode 0, total_received=11214
```

---

¹ perhaps just *unspecified*, I'm not inclined to find out the difference right now

Comment: As a bonus, added a sample with "max complexity" - using blockwise sending on both write and read loops, adding a delay between each write to see the async operations interleaving: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dbfbfb9d23b1dd8)** (yay running on Coliru now).

Comment: Contrast it with [this simple version in 1/5th of the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d4e2029903084bd) which does the same!

Comment: output will be quite large, approx 10Gigs

Comment: Well, it's good I showed all the ins and outs of the various approaches, then (next time, please mention constraints and **the goal** in the question :))

Comment: one question,what is use of send_delay in write_loop, except to wait for 1s(real world, not debug purposes)

Comment: Like I said, that was the entertainment. Do you need delays? No? Then just [drop it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/649e6ca46979616f) (note that - without the delays - the output now doesn't reflect that the IO is truly async)